# prevent a long line enclosed with pre tag from overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have a long single line of text enclosed with `<pre> </pre>` tags.

Is there any way to wrap the line or do I need to add `<br>` into the line of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS property called [white-space: pre-wrap;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), it inserts newline characters when necessary while it preserves sequences of white spaces. See:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <pre class="text">This is a very long line indeed. Way to long for this little box</pre>
</div>
```